# Converting this recursive solution to DP

Tags: algorithm, optimization, recursion, dynamic-programming

Given a stack of integers, players take turns at removing either 1, 2, or 3 numbers from the top of the stack. Assuming that the opponent plays optimally and you select first, I came up with the following recursion:

```
int score(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) return 0;

    if (n <= 3) {
        return sum(v[0..n-1]);
    }

    // maximize over picking 1, 2, or 3 + value after opponent picks optimally
    return max(v[n-1] + min(score(n-2), score(n-3), score(n-4)),
               v[n-1] + v[n-2] + min(score(n-3), score(n-4), score(n-5)),
               v[n-1] + v[n-2] + v[n-3] + min(score(n-4), score(n-5), score(n-6)));
}
```

Basically, at each level comparing the outcomes of selecting 1, 2, or 3 and then your opponent selecting either 1, 2, or 3.

I was wondering how I could convert this to a DP solution as it is clearly exponential. I was struggling with the fact that there seem to be 3 dimensions to it: num of your pick, num of opponent's pick, and sub problem size, i.e., it seems the best solution for `table[p][o][n]` would need to be maintained, where `p` is the number of values you choose, `o` is the number your opponent chooses and `n` is the size of the sub problem.

Do I actually need the 3 dimensions? I have seen this similar problem: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-set-31-optimal-strategy-for-a-game/ , but couldn't seem to adapt it.

Comment: can you give an simple example to clear about the game ?

Comment: @VikramBhat (top of stack)-->12 1 7 10 2 9 3. You can either add 12, 12+1, or 12+1+7 to your score. These numbers are taken off the stack and then your opponent takes their turn at picking 1, 2, or three numbers from the remaining stack. You keep taking turns until there are no numbers left.

Comment: then the one with max count wins right ?

Comment: @VikramBhat right. As in the one with the max sum of number values accumulated--max score.

Comment: "I was wondering how I could convert this to a DP solution as it is clearly exponential." - the trivial way is to do **memoization**.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath memoiztion is not technically equal to DP. DP is bottom up whereas memoization is top down and uses stack as well. You can save lot of space in DP. For example this problem can be done in O(1) extra space using DP by just storing last three sub -solutions.

Comment: @VikramBhat: it's not *technically equal*. It's *one way* to do it. Consequently, your second sentence is false. Look up wikipedia or another trusted source if you don't trust me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Here is way the problem can be converted into DP :-**

```
score[i] = maximum{ sum[i] - score[i+1] , sum[i] - score[i+2] , sum[i] - score[i+3]  }
```

Here `score[i] means max score generated from game [i to n]` where `v[i] is top of stack`. `sum[i] is sum of all elements on the stack from i onwards`. `sum[i]` can be evaluated using a separate DP in **O(N)**. The above DP can be solved using table in **O(N)**

**Edit :-
Following is a DP solution in JAVA :-**

```
public class game {

    static boolean play_game(int[] stack) {
        if(stack.length<=3)
            return true;
        int[] score = new int[stack.length];
        int n = stack.length;
        score[n-1] = stack[n-1];
        score[n-2] = score[n-1]+stack[n-2];
        score[n-3] = score[n-2]+stack[n-3];
        int sum = score[n-3]; 
        for(int i=n-4;i>=0;i--) {
            sum = stack[i]+sum;
            int min = Math.min(Math.min(score[i+1],score[i+2]),score[i+3]);
            score[i] = sum-min;
        }
        if(sum-score[0]<score[0]) 
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] stack = {12,1,7,99,3};
        System.out.printf("I win => "+play_game(stack));
    }
```

**EDIT:-**

For getting a DP solution you need to visualize a problems solution in terms of the smaller instances of itself. For example in this case as both players are playing optimally , after the choice made by first one ,the second player also obtains an optimal score for remaining stack which the **subproblem** of the first one. The only problem here is that how represent it in a **recurrence** . To solve DP you must first define a **recurrence relation** in terms of **subproblem** which precedes the current problem in any way of computation. Now we know that whatever second player  wins , first player loses so effectively first player gains `total sum - score` of second player. As second player as well plays optimally we can express the solution in terms of recursion.

Comment: I can see that this works and what its doing etc., however, I was wondering how you arrived at it; any particular method? Is there any intuitive explanation for putting it together?

Comment: @alh basically you need to find a recurrence relation in terms of smaller problems that can be evaluated independently. Check my edit.